# Issue in Getting Files with Version using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, csom

I want to copy files from one document library folder to another document library folder. here is my code.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                List sourceList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Hassam_Folder");
                CamlQuery caml = CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery();
                Folder rootFolder = sourceList.RootFolder;
                FolderCollection folders = rootFolder.Folders;
                clientContext.Load(folders);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                using (var destinationContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
                {
                    clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                    List DestinationList = destinationContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Ahsan_Folder");
                    Folder rootFolderdest = sourceList.RootFolder;
                    FolderCollection destfolders = rootFolder.Folders;
                    if (folders.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Folder folder in folders)
                        {
                            clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
                            FileCollection sourceFile = folder.Files ;
                            clientContext.Load(sourceFile);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            Folder destRootFolder = DestinationList.RootFolder;
                            FolderCollection foldertocreate = destRootFolder.Folders;
                            foldertocreate.Add(folder.Name);

                            DestinationList.Update();
                            destinationContext.Load(foldertocreate);
                            destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
```

This code create folder with same name to destination document library. Now i Have to add files in destination folders with versions but did not get any idea?
any help should be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void CopyFiles(string url, string listTitle, string srcFolder,string destFolder)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        //context.Credentials = credentials;


        var srcList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}", srcFolder);
        var srcItems = srcList.GetItems(qry);
        context.Load(srcItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i.FileSystemObjectType, i => i["FileRef"], i => i.File));
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var item in srcItems)
        {
            switch (item.FileSystemObjectType)
            {
                case FileSystemObjectType.Folder:
                    var destFolderUrl = ((string)item["FileRef"]).Replace(srcFolder,destFolder);
                    CreateFolder(context.Web,destFolderUrl);
                    break;
                case FileSystemObjectType.File:
                    var destFileUrl = item.File.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(srcFolder, destFolder);
                    item.File.CopyTo(destFileUrl, true);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
} 

private static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string folderUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Folder Url could not be empty");

    var folder = web.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
    web.Context.Load(folder);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    return folder;
}
```